# timepicker increment min time by 1 hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

In my app, users can book appointments from 6:00 AM to 8:00 PM. I'm using [timepicker](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) to do that. I'm setting `minTime: 6:00 AM` and `maxTime : 8:00 PM`. This works but I would actually like to increment minTime by 1hour when the user current time is between 6AM and 7PM. If it is 6:01 AM, the user should not be able to pick 6AM but should be suggested 7AM instead. At 7:01PM, the only time left to pick should be 8PM.

```
//current date
var dateToday = new Date(); 
//get time in US format
//console.log(dateToday.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
var timeNow = dateToday.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
// expected output: 1:15:30 AM
//get time in 12H format
//console.log(dateToday.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT'));
// expected output: 01:15:30

if(timeNow > '6:00:00 AM'&& timeNow < '8:00:00 PM'){
  var minTime = timeNow + 1:00:00;
}else{
  var mintime = '6:00am';
}

//time picker
$(function () {
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
interval: 60,
minTime: minTime,
maxTime: '8:00pm',
dynamic: false,
dropdown: true,
scrollbar: true

});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `new Date().getHours()` to get the hours. You cant use `<` and `>` to strings. Which means you need to convert them to numbers. Since you only need the hour to compare then just get the hours and compare it. Like the following:

```js
var today = new Date();
var hr = today.getHours();
var min = today.getMinutes();
var time = hr >= 12 ? "pm" : "am";

if(hr > 6 && hr < 8) {
  minTime = hr + 1;
}
else {
  minTime = hr
}
minTime = `${minTime > 12 ? minTime - 12 : minTime}:${min}${time}`

//time picker
$(function () {
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
interval: 60,
minTime: minTime,
maxTime: '8:00pm',
dynamic: false,
dropdown: true,
scrollbar: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
//date picker
var dateToday = new Date(); 
//get time in US format
//console.log(dateToday.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
var timeNow = dateToday.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
// expected output: 1:15:30 AM
//get time in 12H format
//console.log(dateToday.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT'));
// expected output: 01:15:30


if(timeNow > '4:00:00 AM'&& timeNow < '8:00:00 PM'){

//add two hours
var dtndate = new Date(); 
dtndate.setHours(dtndate.getHours() + 2);
var minTime = dtndate.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');

}else{
  var minTime = '6:00am';
}


//time picker
$(function () {
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
interval: 60,
minTime: minTime,
maxTime: '8:00pm',
dynamic: false,
dropdown: true,
scrollbar: true

});
});
```