# Display different time slots for different days in Calendar using JQuery daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I have 2 questions

1. I want to display different time slots for different days (like Saturday and Sunday) in calendar. I don't know how to implement this with jQuery daterangepicker.
2. I am trying to increase Hours by 3 hours using " timePickerIncrement: 180," but it's not working.
   I think I am missing something.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
$('.date-time-range').daterangepicker({
    locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A'
    },
    isInvalidDate: function(date) {
    if (date.day() == 0 || date.day() == 5 || date.day() == 6)
      return false;
    return true;
    },
    timePicker: true,
    singleDatePicker: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 180,
    minDate: '<?php echo $todayDate;?>',
    startDate:'<?php echo $startDate;?>',
    drops: 'down',
    buttonClasses: "btn btn-sm",
    applyClass: "btn-success1"
});
```

[image]

Comment: I think your solution is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228004/timepicker-increment-min-time-by-1-hour

Comment: Hi @Mech, i am using daterangepicker not timepicker.